# find caller script path from a library

Tags: php

When execution a script that includes a library, I whant to find from whithin the library the caller script, in Perl I'm using env: `$0` that gives me the path to the caller script. In PHP `__FILE__` gives me the current script, so in the library it gives me the library path not the caller script path.

from perl documentation: **$0 Contains the name of the file containing the Perl script being executed.**

I think It can be done using debug_backtrace(), but there is another better/shorter method ?

**EDIT:**   (added sample code)

file: index.php

```
<?php
require 'locallib.php';
echo 'in original script = '.__FILE__.'<br />';
?>
```

file: locallib.php

```
<?php
require "lib.php";
echo 'in library "'.__FILE__.'"<br />';
?>
```

file: lib.php

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] != '/var/www/html/index.php')
{
    echo "Not allowed";exit;
} else 
{
    echo 'in library "'.__FILE__.'"<br />';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_SERVER);
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Post your sample code also to see what exactly you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
```

[`$_SERVER` reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: +1 works for the main caller script. Doesn't work if there are nested includes, but AFAIK, nothing will work for those - not even a backtrace.

Answer (score 6):

The $_SERVER array is not set when calling a PHP script from the console.

The only way I found of making it work both in web pages and console scripts was with this function:

```
function php_self(){
  $bt = debug_backtrace();
  return $bt[count($bt)-1]['file'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try either of these:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```